# How best to keep track of an unknown number of objects?

Tags: optimization, performance, object-oriented, objective-c, pointers

I have a manager class that will manage an unknown number of objects.  I'm currently storing the objects in a `NSMutableArray` object, and when I need to find one, I iterate through the array comparing pointers.

For example, I have an array called `managedObjects`.  I get a delegate method call:

```
- (void)someDelegateMethod:sender withResults:results {
    for (NSDictionary *managedObjectDict in managedObjects) {
        if (sender == [managedObjectDict objectForKey:@"DelegatedObject"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[managedObjectDict objectForKey:@"Value"]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Objective-C `forin` loops are handled in batches and are extremely fast... but if I were managing thousands of objects, this could potentially take a bit of time to find the right one.

How can I improve this efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linear scan for a unique value immediately screams to me that `managedObjects` should be an `NSDictionary` with `NSValue` wrappers around `Sender*`s as the keys.

In other words, when inserting into `managedObjects` you would do something like `[managedObjects setObject:@{@"Value": @"example} forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer]]`.

Then, in your delegate method, you could retrieve it with:

```
- (void)someDelegateMethod:sender withResults:results {
    NSString* value = [self.managedObjects objectForKey:[NSValue valueForPointer:sender]][@"Value"]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an Objective-C guy but, I do know that if you used some sort of hash table structure and could define a hashcode for these objects, that you'd be able to pull them out much faster.

You said at times you "need to find one", I would assume you would know enough about it to be able to generate its hashcode and check your table for it in O(1) time.